how to get all emojis/emoticons via share link
How can I get all the emojis/emoticons corresponding to the emoji share link?
like: https://t.me/addemoji/CyrillicFont
or like: https://t.me/addemoji/emoji_by_robot
example
I have looked for some methods in the telethon library, pyrogram library and official documents, but have not been able to solve it.
